# extract elements from two arrays with same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I want to extract elements from both arrays with the same url .How can i loop these two arrays and get their content, because it gives me undefined for the news_url and i think it outputs twice the items in the console.

```
function geo(news_array,user_tweets){
    console.log(news_array,user_tweets);
    for (var x=0; x<user_tweets.length; x++) {
        var user = user_tweets[x].user;
        var date = user_tweets[x].date;
        var profile_img = user_tweets[x].profile_img;
        var text = user_tweets[x].text;
        var url=user_tweets[x].url;
        second(user,date,profile_img,text,url);
    }
    function second(user,date,profile_img,text,url){
        for (var i = 0; i < news_array.length; i++) {
            var news_user = news_array[i].news_user;
            var news_date = news_array[i].news_date;
            var news_profile_img = news_array[i].news_profile_img;
            var news_text = news_array[i].news_text;
            var news_url=news_array[i].url;
            if (url==news_array[i].news_url) {
                geocode(user,date,profile_img,text,url,news_user,news_date,news_profile_img,news_text,news_url);
            }
        }
    }
    function geocode(user,date,profile_img,text,url,news_user,news_date,news_profile_img,news_text,news_url) {
        console.log(url,news_url);
            }
    }
```

Comment: what is the structure of those two arrays? You can console.log them and show an output of one or two items of each array.

Comment: I indented your code correctly and it looks like you're missing some closing braces. Can you double-check?

Comment: won't a multi-level for loop suffice?

Comment: @ak_47 Please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can better debug your script.

Comment: The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rhjJb/

Comment: so @sp00m you found a solution?

Comment: OK I FIXED it. the problem was at this line var news_url=news_array[i].url; .... it should have been var news_url=news_array[i].news_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is 
in `news_tweets` function, you add `news_url` to `news_array`. So you should call

> news_array[i].news_url

in `second` function.

I modify your code as

1. `news_url: (item.entities.urls.length > 0)?item.entities.urls[0].url : ''` in `news_tweets` function
2. add close brace `}` for `geo` function and remove `}` from last
3. add `new_array` parameter to `second` function like `second(user, date, profile_img, text, url,news_array);`

Modify code can be tested in http://jsfiddle.net/rhjJb/7/

Comment: nope this is not working.am getting the same result as before

Comment: I update my answer and add modify code in jsfiddle. Let me know your observation about this. Hope this help.

Comment: yeah is correct because i found the answer from before.sorry i didnt tell you...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare some variables before the first `for` loop, so that they can be accessed in the scope of the `second` function. Try to replace your first `for` loop with the following code:

```
var user, date, profile_img, text, url;
for (var x=0; x<user_tweets.length; x++){
    user = user_tweets[x].user;
    date = user_tweets[x].date;
    profile_img = user_tweets[x].profile_img;
    text = user_tweets[x].text;
    url=user_tweets[x].url;
    second(user,date,profile_img,text,url);
}
```

Moreover, in the `if` of your `second` function, `news_array[i].news_url` isn't defined. Use `if (url == news_url)` instead.

Comment: @ak_47 You tried to modify your `if` also, as I wrote at the end of my answer?